# Quiver 2D colormap

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting a dipole field which has a singularity at the origin.
Therefore I want to colour code the arrows to indicate the strength of the field.

Right now I manage to produce the arrows I want but the colour goes along the theta-axis and not along the r-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='polar')

n=30
m=8

thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
radii = np.linspace(0.15, 1, m)
theta, r = np.meshgrid(thetas, radii)
p = .3
Er = p*2*np.cos(theta)#/r**3
Et = p*np.sin(theta)#/r**3

m = np.meshgrid(thetas,radii)
#This is where one should define m such that it results in the color coding I want. Unfortunately, I am not completely sure how the color is decoded in the quiver function.

ax.set_title("Dipole field", va='bottom')
ax.quiver(theta, r, Er * np.cos(theta) - Et * np.sin (theta), Er * np.sin(theta) + Et * np.cos(theta), m, pivot='mid')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like the arrows to be darker near the origin and brighter as the distance r=sqrt (x^2+y^2) from the origin grows.

Comment: I don't know why using `m` even works here, but I would think that you want to replace it by `r`.

Comment: haha, wow thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I didn't know it's as easy as that. Do you know how I can change the color coding to a map like e.g. cm.copper?

Comment: Adding `cmap="copper"`?

Comment: Oh...kay thank you! I am sorry, I was confused because I saw in another example that cmap and color were defined together and then given to the plot function in the color argument as "color=colormap(norm(colors))", so I thought this has to be done here as well but it did not work. Thanks again. If you write your comments as answers, I'd accept them.

Comment: You would need something like `color=colormap(norm(colors))` in case you'd use the `color` argument. But here you use the `C` argument, hence everything works as expected for any ScalarMappable like scatter, imshow etc as well. Maybe you can write this up as answer yourself?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, alright, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks to the comments of @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest, I can answer the question as follows: The C-argument in the quiver function can just take a function of the plotting coordinates. Hence, it suffices to add "r" in the quiver function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='polar')

n=30
m=8

thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
radii = np.linspace(0.15, 1, m)
theta, r = np.meshgrid(thetas, radii)
p = .3
Er = p*2*np.cos(theta)#/r**3
Et = p*np.sin(theta)#/r**3
#we leave out the 1/r**3 part because it would make our arrows infinitely long near the origin.
#Instead we use a colormap to indicate the strength of the field as follows

ax.set_title("Dipole field", va='bottom')
ax.quiver(theta, r, Er * np.cos(theta) - Et * np.sin (theta), Er * np.sin(theta) + Et * np.cos(theta), r, pivot='mid', cmap='YlGnBu_r')
plt.show()
```

The result looks as follows:
[image]

The cmap command makes the color coding appear according to the cmap YlGnBu_r.

More color coding maps are given here:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
and here
http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html.